# SelectPicture.aspx > Upload profile picture thru Central Admin

Tags: user-profile

Central Admin still can't upload user's picture. We just updated to Feb 2013 CU thinking it will fix the issue.

1. Latest CU in place
2. Central Admin getting error
3. User profile service is running and only 1 instance of this is present in our multi-server farm. (FIM sync and everything else revolves around user profile works).

ULS:

```
Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://AppServer:20000/_layouts/SelectPicture2.aspx?Type=User&accountname=CONTOSO%5CspTestUser&ApplicationID=6a3b1168%2Dfe19%2D434b%2Db46b%2Dc8c4d50790f5&IsDlg=1))
```

I verified and made sure this is the right user profile app.

Error:

```
Unhandled exception caught during execution of Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.PageBase::ErrorHandler(). Exception information: Exception information: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetRawPartitionID(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean ignorePrivacy)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean backwardCompatible)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.LoadPictureLibrary()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.<OnLoad>b__0()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.OnLoad(EventArgs ea)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetRawPartitionID(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean ignorePrivacy)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean backwardCompatible)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.LoadPictureLibrary()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.<OnLoad>b__0()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.OnLoad(EventArgs ea)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.   
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetRawPartitionID(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean ignorePrivacy)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean backwardCompatible)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.LoadPictureLibrary()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.<OnLoad>b__0()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.OnLoad(EventArgs ea)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the user attempting the change a User Profile Service Administrator? Do they have Full Control?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working under Active Directory?
If so you could try mapping the field in the AD with the field Picture in the user profile.

Comment: In development - CA > User profile svc > Manage user properties, the picture property is URL type and mapped to nothing. With these setup it works in DEV.

Comment: Maybe the synchronization was not finished when yo did the upgrade. Try the following:
1. Stop and start user profile service application synchronization service in central administration > manage service on this server
2. Make sure that the "User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" or "User Profile to SharePoint Quick Synchronization" timer jobs are working fine http://CA/_admin/ServiceJobDefinitions.aspx 
3. Disable both timer jobs and enable them again.
4. Run stsadm -o Execadmsvcjobs

Let me know if that works.

Comment: @ Matt: Yes, the user being spServiceAccount who is in Farm Admin and has full permission for User Profile Service Application (this account is in Administrators with Full Control and Permissions with Full Control)

Comment: @Alvmad: Why do I want to mess with Sync job. Everything works as far as User sync goes. We dont store pictures in AD. I am talking about when Central Administrator Admin tries to upload a picture (manually) for a user then I get the error.